# Using Address Instead Of Longitude And Latitude With react-native-maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

```
<MapView

          region={latitude: 28.568806,
                  longitude: 173.765210,
                  latitudeDelta: 0.7,
                  longitudeDelta: 0.7}
          provider={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? PROVIDER_DEFAULT : PROVIDER_GOOGLE }
        >
```

I want to provide address to region instead of latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can this link http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=

```
fetch('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + 'turkey').then(res => this.setState({region: res.result.geometry.location}));
```

[image]

that is, you send the address, it will return you json

Answer (score -2):

You Should use something to decode lat, lng into readable address I'm using this library [react-native-geocoder](https://github.com/devfd/react-native-geocoder)

Comment: He asked exactly the opposite, how to convert the "full address" to "lat and lng"